# DateTime Format Follow by date in CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv, datetime, datetime-format

Hye guys.. need some help from you.. sorry for my broken english.
actually, what im doin is, i need to upload some data from csv file into Microsoft Access which is contain a LASTDATE date.. for coding overall okay. but i getting problem with date.. when i upload into database, i have to insert follow by LASTDATE date in csv file..but what i get is, in database, it refer to current time on laptop.

for example, LASTUPDATE is 16/10/2017.. when i upload, LASTDATE will follow by current time on my laptop..

here is a code..

```
Public Function GetDateFormatToDB(vDateTime As String) As String

    Try
        Dim format As String = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        Dim expenddt As Date
        Date.TryParseExact(vDateTime, format, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, expenddt)
        Return expenddt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try


End Function
```

Comment: Please post code that could reproduce the problem. It is called a [mcve] This code doesn't tell anything about your problem

Comment: If the issue is with the DB insert, show *that* code.  You should also set `Option Strict On` - that code promises to return a string (which seems the wrong type for a DB insert) but then returns a date in the code.  Also, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: By the way your function should return a string but you return a Date. They are not the same thing. To resolve your mistake the compiler converts your result to a string with results that cannot be trusted. Set Option Explicit On in your project properties

Comment: okay Steve.. i wanna try first

Comment: If the issue is that you want to save Date and not DateTime to Access, it is the way you are saving the data.  The code posted has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return `Nothing` in case of an error your function should have `Nullable(Of Date)` (or `Date?`) as return value.

If you only want to store the date-part of a `Date` object, use the `Date` property of your `Date` object.
In your code snippet it would be `expenddt.Date`. This way you get rid of the time-part of the `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.FromOADate(Double.Parse(myValue)).ToShortDateString()

this will help

Comment: Hi Nico, welcome to SO. When giving answers, please explain why your code works and/or how it resolves OP's question :)